# Chrome Native Client, errors using onKeyDown event

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-nativeclient

I'm trying to get a very basic Chrome Native Client application running. What I'd like to do is respond to keystrokes, for example by displaying "You pressed X" whenever a user presses a key. I've been at it all day, but every time I press a key, I get "**Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'postMessage'**".

The errors are all in the Javascript; the Native Client C++ module works fine.

Javascript in head of document:

```
myModule = null;  // Global application object.

function moduleDidLoad() {
    myModule = document.getElementById('mymodule');

    alert("module loaded!") // this works

    myModule.postMessage('hello'); // this works, and posts 'hello' to the module

   // ERROR
   document.body.onkeydown = function() {myModule.postMessage('hi');}
}
```

In page:

```
<div id="listener">
   <script type="text/javascript">

     var listener = document.getElementById('listener');
      listener.addEventListener('load', moduleDidLoad, true);

   </script>

  <embed name="nacl_module"
   id="mymodule"
   width=0 height=0     
   src="mymodule.nmf"
   type="application/x-nacl" />
</div>
```

I've tried it about 15 different ways: by adding it to the body tag with addEventListener, by adding it directly to the body tag with onKeyDown... nothing works.

I have experience with C/C++ and PHP but my Javascript is really weak. I think I must be missing something fundamental and obvious.

Comment: why are you trying to make a global variable? anyway, javascript only has function scope, and if you omit "var" it will be "global" anyway. so don't think that it makes a difference that you assign it outside the function!

Comment: Hi-- most of this code is straight from the Hello World tutorial on the Native Client site, including that global variable. The only thing that's mine, really, is the part about listening to the onKeyDown event. I'm just trying to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Elsewhere on the page, the DIV that contains the game module was having its contents changed, which removed the module from memory.