# nodejs jsdom TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'postMessage'

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsdom

This is a page from my Nodejs Express app, routers/index.js page
I am trying to parse some sites - here are two pieces of code as an example. 
After getting the page I use jsdom module to work with data. But there is one problem - othersite.com in this example works fine, while site.com crashes after parsing and rendering the page (as it seems to me) with an error:

```
http://s7.addthis.com/static/r07/core159.js:4
){!_ate.bro.ie6&&!_ate.bro.ie7&&W&&W.contentWindow&&W.contentWindow.postMessag
                                                                    ^
TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'postMessage'
    at Object.r [as msg] (http://s7.addthis.com/static/r07/core159.js:4:6291)
    at Object.window._ate.m.initPostMessage (http://s7.addthis.com/static/r07/core159.js:7:11410)
    at null._onTimeout (http://s7.addthis.com/static/r07/core159.js:7:7874)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:110:15)
```

There are other conditional blocks that produce the same error, though there is not so much code there.
Can anyone tell me what's the problem?

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
var url_parts = url.parse(req.url, true),
    query = url_parts.query,
    video_url,
    file_url,
    videoTitle,
    embedCode,
    remoteAddr = req.connection.remoteAddress,
    base64_encode = require('base64').encode;
if (query.link) {
        var pathObj = url.parse(query.link, true);
        var options = {
            host: pathObj.host,
            port: 80,
            path: pathObj.path,
            headers: {
                "X-forwarder-for" : "90.90.90.90" // just sample ip
            }
        };
        http.get(options, function(response){

            var allChunk = '';
            response.on('data', function(chunk) {
                    allChunk += chunk;
            });
            response.on('end', function(){
                var doc = jsdom.jsdom(allChunk);
                var serializedChunk = doc.documentElement.outerHTML;
                jsdom.env(
                    serializedChunk,
                    ["http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"],
                    function (errors, window) {
                        remoteAddr = remoteAddr;
                        videoTitle = window.$('title').text();
                        var rawHtml = window.$('body').html();
                        var handler = new htmlparser.DefaultHandler(function (error, dom) {});
                        var parser = new htmlparser.Parser(handler);
                        parser.parseComplete(rawHtml);
                        var objectDom = handler.dom;
                        if (query.link.indexOf('site.com') != -1) {
                            var blockHTML = window.$('#player embed').attr('flashvars');
                            var flash_vars_url = url.parse('/?' + blockHTML, true);
                            var queryFlashVars = flash_vars_url.query;
                            file_url = queryFlashVars.flv_url;
                            embedCode = window.$('input[name="media_embed_code"]').val();
                            res.render('link', { title: 'source link', link: file_url, videoTitle: videoTitle, embedCode: embedCode, sourceLink: query.link });
                        } else if (query.link.indexOf('othersite.com') != -1) {
                            file_url = window.$('.downloadList li a').attr('href');
                            var embedObject = /\$\('#clip_text'\).val\(*"([^"]*)/g.exec(rawHtml);
                            embedCode = embedObject[1];
                            res.render('link', { title: 'source link', link: file_url, videoTitle: videoTitle, embedCode: embedCode, sourceLink: query.link });

                        } else {
                            res.status(404);
                            res.render('error', {
                                message: 'Not found',
                                error: {}
                            });
                        }

                    }
                );

            });
        }).on("error", function(e){
            console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
        }).end();
} else {
    res.render('index', { title: 'title' });
}
```

});

I will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Well as you can see from Error Description :

You trying to call ate.bro.ie6&&!_ate.bro.ie7&&W&&W.contentWindow&&W.contentWindow.postMessage

But content Window does not have such method. Possible reason you load something and overwritten that module.

In source provided(and from de-obfuscation of http://s7.addthis.com/static/r07/core159.js ) I see that's its some library on server side which seems to emulate "Browser" Window Object behavior... But you destroyed windows context so its unable to work.

I think [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9244911/chrome-native-client-errors-using-onkeydown-event) similar issue

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like there is code that tries to execute [`window.postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage) and this method does not exist in jsdom. This code tests whether `window.postMessage` can be called at all:

```
var jsdom = require("jsdom");

var document = jsdom.env({
    html: "<html><head><script>window.postMessage();</script></head><body></body></html>",
    features: {
        FetchExternalResources: ["script"],
        ProcessExternalResources: ["script"]
    },
    done: function (errors, w) {
        console.log(errors);
    }
});
```

Produces this output:

```
[ { type: 'error',
    message: 'Running file:///tmp/t2/test.js:undefined:undefined<script> failed.',
    data:
     { error: [TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'postMessage'],
       filename: 'file:///tmp/t2/test.js:undefined:undefined<script>' } } ]
```

I've also checked the code:

```
$ npm install jsdom
$ cd node_modules/jsdom
$ grep postMessage `find . -type f`
[no results]
```